# Is there a way to execute Excel macro using Python on server?

Tags: python, excel, vba, server, xlsxwriter

I am having a Flask App deployed on Windows Server, which exports a file in xlsx/xlsm format.

I've put the vbaProject.bin to attach it to the xlsx file and make it xlsm (macro enabled) using xlsxwriter engine.

I'm not able to execute the macro on the server as the MS Office suite is not installed on the server.

Is there a way to execute the macro on the server without getting MS Excel installed on the machine; by using some python library or converting the macro/VBA code to some executable code on the server?

Comment: To excecute VBA you need Office installed. But what you can do is rebuild what ever your VBA does in Python (re-write the code) and let Python do the job instead of VBA. Therefore exist libraries to access Excel files. But you will have to re-write the code on your own. There does not exist any automatic translation for VBA to Python.

Comment: Thanks, @Pᴇʜ for the response. Is there a way to convert VBA to some other server executable code like .NET or something, instead of manual conversion to Python. Because VBA code is doing typical Excel aesthetics which are less likely to be achieved through core Python code

Comment: There are libraries for Python that provide more or less the same functionality as VBA. No matter in which language you convert you will need to do it manually. Even VBA to VB.NET will need manual conversion.